# Complete Residue Systems Modulo m

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $m$ and $n$ are integers with greatest common divisor $1$. For convenience assume that both are greater than $1$.
Prove that the set { $0 · n, 1 · n, 2 · n, . . . ,(m − 1) · n$ } is a complete residue system modulo
$m$.

I am blank on how to solve this problem. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think differences. Suppose $0\leq a,b<m$.

$$an\equiv bn(mod~m)\Longrightarrow n(a-b)\equiv0(mod~m)\Longrightarrow m|n(a-b)$$
$$\Longrightarrow m|(a-b)~~~~~(1)\Longrightarrow a=b~~~~~(2)$$

$(1)$ $\gcd (m,n)=1$ implies that multiplying a number by $n$ will not change whether or not it is divisible by $m$. (Multiplying by $n$ can't "contribute" any factors of $m$ to $(a-b)$.)

$(2)$ Since $0\leq a,b<m$, the only possible multiple of $m$ that can be obtained from $a-b$ is $0$. Thus $a=b$.

An equivalent way of writing $(p~is~true)\Rightarrow (q~is~true)$ for any logical statements p and q is $(q~is~false)\Rightarrow (p~is~false)$. . In our case, this is $a\neq b\Rightarrow an\not\equiv bn(mod~m)$.

This last result implies $0, n,~2n,~3n,\ldots (m-1)n$ are all distinct which was what we wanted to show.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused on how to go from there. I can see what you have done, but do not know the progression to a complete proof.

Comment: @Mathier Recall Euclid's lemma: since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime and $m$ divides $n(a-b)$, $m$ must in fact divide $a-b$. But $\lvert a - b\rvert < m$, so...

Comment: so... $m$ cannot divide $∣a−b∣$

Comment: remember, $m|0$ since $0=km$ for some integer $k$ (in this case, $k=0$)

Comment: @Alex Provost How does this help prove that the set presented above is a complete residue system modulo $m$?

Comment: I am also not familiar with Euclid' lemma. Is it a part of Congruences?

Comment: @Crazed Then better get used to Euclid's lemma, as it is essential here and elsewhere (e.g. it's the key to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic).